# mathematica to python flatten

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

I am having trouble visualizing how to convert the following to python. mask2D is a 59x31 array. mask1D produces a 1829 array. Refs2D is a 50x59x31 array, so physically it is 50 still of a 59x31 image.

```
mask1D = Flatten[mask2D];
indexmask1D = Flatten[Position[mask1D, 1]];
Refs1D = Transpose[Flatten[Refs2D, {2, 3}]][[All, indexmask1D]];
```

But in Mathematica, indexmask1D is a 1201 array. So I concluded that indexmask1D could be represented by:

```
x = []
for i in range(len(mask1D)):
if mask1D[i] == 1:
    x.append(i)
indexmask1D = np.asarray(x)
```

My issue comes to the Refs1D line. I don't understand how to correctly flatten Refs2D. In Mathematica, the flattening results in a 1829x50 array. I can understand physically that it is going pixel to pixel in the image and collecting every pixel from every image (producing 1829 pixels with 50 values at each pixel). I don't know enough Mathematica to know what the [[All, indexmask1D]] is doing, because the transpose part is a 50x1829 matrix and indexmask1D is a 1201 matrix. How can you multiply and how can you write the code in python?

Edit: I ended up bluntly doing this:

```
x1 = []
for a,b in enumerate(Refs2D):
    for c,d in enumerate(b):
        for e,f in enumerate(d):
            x1.append(Refs2D[:,c,e])
x1a = np.asarray(x1[:59*31])
Refs1D = np.ndarray.transpose(x1a)[:,indexmask1D]
```

Comment: I personally think you could ask in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ first for a detailed explanation on what those lines do, rather than ask for a straight translation.

Answer (score 0):

this may help, rewriting that one line in mathematica that may be a bit easier to understand:

```
 Transpose[Flatten[Refs2D, {2, 3}]][[All, indexmask1D]]
```

is equivalent to:

```
 Table[Table[Flatten[Refs2D[[i]]][[k]], {k, indexmask1D}],
      {i,Length@Refs2D}]
```